# getContentResolver() not returning mp3s?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a basic music app, but my getContentResolver doesnt seem to return the mp3s on the emulator for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
columns = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC
};

cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1",
        null,
        null
);
```

Now, I dragged a folder of mp3s to the phone, and moved them to the 'music' folder of the internal storage.  They are there, they have a filesize.  When I loop through the cursor I get the following list:

```
<unknown>: KeypressSpacebar, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Lock, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Unlock, ui, isMusic: 1
(c) 2012 Android Open Source Project: Video Record, ui, isMusic: 1
(c) 2012 Android Open Source Project: Camera Shutter, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Effect_Tick, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: camera_focus, ui, isMusic: 1
(c) 2012 Android Open Source Project: Video Stop, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Dock, ui, isMusic: 1
Copyright 2013 Android Open Source Project: KeypressInvalid, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Trusted, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: KeypressStandard, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: KeypressReturn, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Low Battery, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: Undock, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: KeypressDelete, ui, isMusic: 1
<unknown>: WirelessChargingStarted, ui, isMusic: 1
```

That should be `artist: title, album, is_music`.

Why isn't it picking up my mp3's? Do I need to refresh it or something? Restarting the emulator doesnt make any difference either.

EDIT: I moved the files to external storage, and switched the getContentResolver to look there, and now the files show.  But I dont understand why it wouldnt show from internal?  And also, why the files that *are* showing are listed as Is_Music, they are UI surely?

Edit2: I loop through the cursor like this:

```
if(cursor != null) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String artist = cursor.getString(0);
            String title = cursor.getString(1);
            String album = cursor.getString(2);

        Log.d("MediaContent::", "getMusicFiles: " + artist + ": " + title + ", " + album + ", isMusic: " + String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(4)));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: How are you getting values from cursor? Can you post that code

Comment: @samirk433 I have updated the question, although Im not sure how I could be doing that differently.

Comment: I meant, how you feed data to `artist `, `title` etc..

Comment: @samirk433 oh sorry, i missed that out.

Comment: take a debug point on while loop and check values of these variables, the given logcat report doesn't seem of it